# Get lowest value in left join from intermediate table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following tables in PostgreSQL 13:

```
+---------+--------------+------+
| student | student_exam | exam |
+---------+--------------+------+
| id      | student_id   | id   |
|         | exam_id      | name |
|         | grade        |      |
+---------+--------------+------+
```

I want to fetch each student's lowest grade's exam, with the following rows as result:

```
+------------+-------+-----------+
| student_id | grade | exam_name |
+------------+-------+-----------+
| ...        | ...   | ...       |
+------------+-------+-----------+
```

My closest approach, not checking if its the minimum grade:

```sql
select
    student.id as student_id,
    student_exam.grade as grade,
    exam.name as exam_name
from
    student s
    left join student_exam as se on se.student_id = s.id
    left join exam as e on se.exam_id = e.id
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (s.id) s.id as student_id,
       se.grade as grade, e.name as exam_name
from student s left join
     student_exam se
     on se.student_id = s.id left join
     exam e
     on se.exam_id = e.id
order by s.id, se.grade;
```

`Distinct on` is a convenient Postgres extension.  It returns one row per combination of values of the expression(s) in parentheses.  This row is the "first" row for each combination of values.  The `order by` specifies which row -- the first `order by` keys need to match the values in the `distinct on`.  The remaining keys define "first".

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm :)

However, my query went from 150ms to 800ms. Is distinct that expensive?

Comment: @Zeswen . . . Actually, it is the sorting that is expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Why `LEFT JOIN`? (data without `student_exam` is of not useful to you) You can use the `INNER JOIN` and `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
select
    s.id as student_id,
    se.grade as grade,
    e.name as exam_name
from
    student s
    join student_exam as se on se.student_id = s.id
    join exam as e on se.exam_id = e.id
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (select 1 from student_exam se_ 
      where se_.student_id = se.student_id
        and se_.grade < se.grade )
```

Or you can use analytical function as follows:

```
select * from
(select
    s.id as student_id,
    se.grade as grade,
    e.name as exam_name,
    rank() over (partition by s.id order by se.grade) as rn
from
    student s
    join student_exam as se on se.student_id = s.id
    join exam as e on se.exam_id = e.id) t
where rn = 1
```